# Showing that $x\cdot z_x - y\cdot z_y= 0, z = f(xy)$ with the general chain rule in coordinates theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Preamble**: What I mean by the general chain rule in coordinates is that let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable at $a \in A$, and $g:f[A] \to \mathbb{R}^l$ be differentiable at $b = f(a)$. Then the composition $(g \circ f)$ is differentiable at $a$, and its partial derivatives are given by $$D_j(g\circ f)_i(a) = \sum_{k=1}^{m}D_kg_i(f(a))D_jf_k(a) \text{ for }i=1,\dots,l, j=1,\dots,n$$

Now consider the differential equation $xf_x(xy) - yf_y(xy) = 0$, where the dimension of the range of $f$ is not specified, but we can assumed it to be at least one. The equality can be easily shown to be true by just applying the chain rule to $f$, so that

$$x z_x(xy) - y z_y(xy) = x\frac{\partial z}{\partial xy}\frac{\partial xy}{\partial x} - y\frac{\partial z}{\partial xy}\frac{\partial xy}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial xy}(xy - xy) = 0.$$

**Question**: To me it seems that there shouldn't be any reason why we can't frame and proof the equation above with the given formula of the chain rule in coordinates. However when I actually try to do this, my brain completely freezes. What I mean is that given that $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, (x, y) \mapsto xy$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, how do we even know what component functions of $f$are of interest to us, i.e. what should $i$ be in the formula?

Edit: For achieving, this is the exercise 4.5.6. (pp. 164) of Calculus and Analysis in Euclidean Space by Shurman et al.

Comment: Replacing $x$ by $x_1$ and $y$ by $x_2$ will help you to switch your mind to indices notation.

Comment: The equation $xf_x(xy) - yf_y(xy) = 0$ is a bit non-sensical to me. The fact that $f$ has both $x$ and $y$ partials suggests that $f$ takes in at least two inputs, i.e., $f(x,y)$. Where is the second variable in $f_x(xy)$?

Comment: @EuYu There isn't. This is the exercise 4.5.6. (pp. 164) of Calculus and Analysis in Euclidean Space by Shurman et al., and the exercise reads as: "*Show that if $z = f(xy)$, then $x, y, z$ satisfy the differential equation $x\cdot z_x - y\cdot z_y = 0$*", where the author had previously defined the notation $f_x$ to mean the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t. its $x$ component.

Comment: Then $z_x = y f'(x y)$ and $z_y = x f'(x y)$ and the relation is true.

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes, the equation is indeed true. But my question wasn't that much about its truthness, but rather how you'd frame the proof in terms of the algebra/vector notation given by the general chain rule in coordinates.

Comment: @EpsilonAway You are misunderstanding partial derivatives. The expression $z_x$ is the partial derivative of the function $z(x,y) = f(xy)$ with respect to $x$. The expression $f_x(xy)$ is the $x$-partial of $f$ (which doesn't make sense in this case) evaluated at $xy$. Can you see why they're inequivalent?

Comment: @EuYu I see! Thanks for pointing this out! For the record, so far I've thought that $z_x(x, y) = f_x(x,y)$, as $z = f(xy)$. However my question still remains even after clearing up the notation.

Comment: @EpsilonAway I guess it's not very clear what you want. The argument you've supplied in your OP doesn't work. For example, the expression $\partial z/\partial(xy)$ is non-sensical. If you want a proper proof of the equality, then Gribouillis has already supplied you with one. In this case, $z:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the composition of the functions $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}::(x,y)\mapsto xy$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Applying the chain rule, in the form you've supplied, to $z = f \circ g$ gives you the answer.